# Can't select chat profile if user is in too many rooms

Tags: bug, chat

So I noticed a curious thing today. If you want to view a person's chat profile for any reason, and they are in a large number of chat rooms, the following happens:

[image: chat scroll off screen]

As you can see, the large list of chat rooms means that the part where you can view their profile is shoved off-screen. Scrolling up/down on the page just moves the window, but doesn't let you actually get to the profile link.

Is there some way around this (short of putting a limit of how many rooms a person can be in, to keep the list bounded)?

Comment: Dang, my usual Google-fu failed me today :(

Comment: In your defense it should have been fixed by now anyway :P